# 'layout_height' attribute should be defined

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

I'm getting annoying "'layout_height' attribute should be defined" lint error.
Although I have it defined in my style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

So I tried to turn off this lint rule, but with no avail:
[image]

How can I solve this annoying behavior? Or can I just turn off lint rules?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/turn-off-lint-error-checking.html  this may help you

Comment: Unfortunately this is Eclipse, and I use Android Studio

Comment: thats cool, then check this... http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

Answer (score 1):

You should not be defining layout_height or layout_width in the app theme. These need to go in every layout xml file. In fact, all attributes starting with 'layout' should not go in any theme or style document, these should stay in their corresponding layout file (e.g. layout_marginTop or layout_gravity'. That's probably why you're getting lint errors.

Comment: I would argue: 1) it is allowed, 2) setting layout_height and layout_width to wrap_content by default significantly reduces verbosity of the XMLs.

Comment: Layout attributes are not meant to be in styles or themes as they can be situational depending on the layout. For example where a RelativeLayout would need a layout_centerHoriontal to centre a view horizontally a LinearLayout would need layout_gravity. They have the layout_ prefix on them for a reason, so you know not to use them in styles. I would imagine you're getting your error as you've got a view without layout_width and layout_height as you think you don't need them.

Comment: That's right. And I'm not trying to style this stuff. What I do (and did for many years already) is specify default values in the theme. Thus many lines in XML can be saved. But I guess your valid point is what makes this to be caught by lint. 
How do I turn it off though?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while I was creating a new XML layout for Card View.
Even after giving it the `layout_height` attribute, it gives me the same error.
I cleared all the code after copying it and pasted back the previous code but this time I had no error logs.

What just happened?!

May be the XML code was not getting sync so it kept displaying the error.

Comment: Just had the same problem; for any future readers; I was missing android: before layout_height.